# Drush disable module updates email notifications

Tags: drush

Is there a Drush command to disable email notifications about Module updates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can turn off just the email notify feature like this:

```
drush vdel update_notify_emails
```

(See in update.fetch.inc: `$notify_list = variable_get('update_notify_emails', '');`)

You might also want to consider the following alternative:

```
drush pm-disable update
```

This will completely disable the update module on your live server, which will also disable email notifications about Module updates.  At first blush, you might be sad that you won't be able to see the module updates page on your live server any more; however, you should really be doing your updating on a development machine anyway, so you can just re-enable update on the dev server.

To automatically re-enable the update module every time you sql-sync from live to dev, see [symc_enable.drush.inc](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/sync_enable.drush.inc).

Finally, to insure that your *dev* machine does not send out unwanted email notifications, enable the devel module, and then add to your settings.php file:

```
$conf['mail_system'] = array(
  'default-system' => 'DevelMailLog',
);
$conf['devel_debug_mail_directory'] = '/path/to/dir/to/save/email';
```

Then, devel will intercept all email that is sent and write it into the target directory instead of emailing it.

Comment: Cool, does that conf var for emails work without having to set `$conf['mail_system']` to `DevelMailLog`?

Comment: Oops, thanks, I forgot that step.  I'll go edit the answer.

Comment: It worked with an error Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in update_settings() (line 38 of /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/update/update.settings.inc).

Comment: Sorry, update module was not consistent in its use of that variable.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, unless you installed a module that provides functionality to disable email notifications about Module updates, and drush command to switch it (or at least configuration in variable that can be easily changed with drush).

There is no such option in Drupal Core as far as I can remember.

Comment: I guess one option would be turn the module off altogether, but apart from that I think `hook_mail_alter()` is the only option in a custom module

Comment: I was actually thinking that there might be a configuration variable that can be set through vset command

Comment: @Fahad The settings page is at /admin/reports/updates/settings, there doesn't seem to be a kill switch there

Comment: @Clive You are right, option to disable email notifications is available at the time of installation only.

Comment: @Clive Just noticed if we remove email address from E-mail addresses from /admin/reports/updates/settings page it will not send any notifications. May be email field can be set blank through vset

Comment: I looked up the variable name in update.fetch.inc; see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but I just had to set this up for our devops for Drupal 8.
@Clive is correct, you can disable by removing email addresses in /admin/reports/updates/settings.
There can be more than one, and I wanted to make sure to remove them all.
It is not obvious how to set an empty array using config-set, so I used php-eval.

```
drush php-eval '\Drupal::service("config.factory")
                ->getEditable("update.settings")
                ->set("notification.emails", [])
                ->save();'
```